# Can't install ERMaster plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I cannot install ERMaster in my eclipse as shown in the installation manual

> http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/

When I try to install in my eclipse, it says

> This repository is currently not available

Anyone knows alternative way to install?

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, you will have to configure that. Otherwise: did you check that the repository is there?

Comment: yes, I check the repository link ermaster.sourceforge.net/update-site ,I did not get anything when i entered this url.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The updatesite gives a gateway timeout. It doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This is NOT an alternative way, but a link to a totally different product.

Answer (score 1):

Open your eclipse and then go to **Help** -> **Install New Softwares**. Use this URL (http://ermaster.sourceforge.net/update-site/) to install ERMaster:

*Unfortunately, it doesn't work on Eclipse **Photon** version* for me.

Try below...

Download ERMaster jar from [official site](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ermaster/) and copy it to the **dropins** folder under your eclipse installation directory. And then restart the eclipse.